# Multimedia keyboard not working after power loss

Tags: shutdown, ps2-keyboard

I have a PS/2 multimedia keyboard and everytime my computer shutsdown unexpectedly (i.e power failure) my keyboard turns on numlock while the computer is off. When I start the computer, the numeric keypad doesn't work at all and I can't control numlock state either.

Keys are also pressed randomly while I type something.
Nothing works until I unplug and replug the ps/2 connector.

What is causing this? 
What can be done to fix the issue?